# iOS 11 Screenshot Markup

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

iOS 11 added a markup option after taking a screenshot, how can I programmatically apply this option after programmatically taking a screenshot? it directly gets saved to photos without providing the markup/share option.

I use the code below to take and save the screenshot

```
@IBAction func takeScreenshot(_ sender: Any) {
   let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
   let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

   layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
   let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

[image: This screenshot is only available when I manually take screenshot, is there a way that I can programmatically achieve this?]

Comment: I don't think that you can do it without having to code it yourself and editing the original image

Comment: I would suggest showing a message that explains how to take a screenshot (remember to make it device-dependent, as the position of the power button is different on some devices and the iPhone X has no home button), and make sure to hide it once the screenshot is taken.

Answer (score 2):

Instant Markup is not documented anywhere in Apple's Reference Docs, so I think its safe to assume this isn't made public through their SDK.

Instead you would have to create your own markup editor.

Note: You may not change the way actual device screenshots are handled (when the user presses Home and Lock together) [as per Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/screenshots/).