# How to implement Instant Markup feature in iOS programatically

Tags: ios, swift

in iOS 11 if we take screenshot manually we have the option for Instant Markup, but is it possible to implement the same behaviour through code? Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldBhq.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 11 Screenshot Markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350483/ios-11-screenshot-markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, I don't think `Instant Markup` is available for other than screenshot and it's shown from OS not through code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement PencilKit to do so.